# Get currently logged in user's UID — Dropbox

Tags: oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to find out the currently logged in user's UID (User's UID in Dropbox) so that I can use an existing access_token instead of requesting for a new one?

I was thinking of storing access_tokens with the respective UIDs in a database.

If not, is there a better way to handle returning users?

Comment: When you say "currently user's UID", are you talking about logged into Dropbox or logged into your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the basic idea backwards. You need to identify the user to your application in order to pick the correct OAuth Tokens to use. You can't get the user's Dropbox UID without having their tokens. Without having the tokens, you can't identify who the user is.

Comment: Ok, basically no one logs into my app. The only authentication/identifying part is authenticating with Dropbox via OAuth.
So you're telling me that there isn't a way to know who the user is before authenticating via OAuth unless I setup a Log In system for the app.

Comment: Yes. The OAuth Tokens are tied to a user. Unless you know which user you are requesting information from, you don't know which OAuth tokens to use. If I go to your site and authorize you to access by Dropbox account, then you need someway to tie back the OAuth tokens to me. The next time I go to your site, you need to be able to identify me, so that you can make sure to use the Dropbox OAuth tokens associated with my account.

Comment: Ah well, guess I should stick to one of the SSO services.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the Dropbox authorization screen as your login system.